# want to include one html page to another page in the client-side

Tags: html

I have a common header for all the html pages, so I want the header.html page to be included in another html page. 
Suggest some ways as this header needs to be given in all the html pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    header#arriba {
        width:1350px;
        height:30px;
        clear:both;
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:red;
        color: white;

    }

    header#arriba img {
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin:2px 700px 2px 35px; /* YOU CAN ADJUST IMAGES SPACE WITH THIS MARGINS */
    } 

    header img{
      float:left;
      margin-right:5px;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="arriba">
        <h2><img src="header.png" alt="1" width="150px" height="25px"/>Data</h2>    
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I include this into another html page without giving this code again and again into all the other pages???

Comment: Are you using any framework?? You can use any template engine for that, almost all handle this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the extension of all the pages from "html" to "shtml".

Create an HTML Page having your header.

And now what you can do it you can include your header into any shtml page by the following command

```
<!--#include virtual="Web/Controls/TopPanel.html" -->
```

The only thing which is the prerequisite is the SSI(Server Side Injection) should be supported by the server.

Comment: What i mean by Server Side injection is that you must be having an server where you will be hosting your website(If it is a static HTML website or Web Forms or MVC). Like of you are hosting it on IIS, then IIS shoudl support Server Side Injection. so whenever a request is made to your pages it will actually include that header part on server into your pages and then will transfer the HTML to the client..

Answer (score 0):

Client side page inclusion is only possible using AJAX. Look at jQuery for a simple AJAX library.

Example code (assuming jQuery is included):

```
$.ajax("includes/header.html").then(function(data) {
    $('body').prepend(data);
});
```

This will insert the html in the includes/header.html at the top of the body element.
You could also insert stuff to the head. (replace 'body' with 'head')